# Google Sites Login System

Tags: javascript, google-sites

I know this question has seemingly been asked. Without solution.

That said, I did try to do my research on it and I haven't found a complete solution.

I'm trying to create a login system for google sites. Login on the homepage and until you do you cannot view any other page or be able to access it. That said, I'm honestly struggling with the of viewing other pages, so how would I do that?

I have considered making the menu myself and disabling the normal one - but then couldn't they just type the url www.site/page-i-don't-want-you-to-see?

So what's the solution? Adding googlescript on every page to verify? EDIT: Very noteworthy to point out: https://support.google.com/sites/answer/1387646?hl=en&ref_topic=1387383 there is page restrictions if you want to do it manually. A bit impractical when you could to sites that should have a decent number of people.

What I DO have done right now is a login app using a spreadsheet ( Don't worry - passwords are encoded. Only reason I am using a spreadsheet and not a database is I'm making the site for someone else as well) which you can create an account and try to log in.

I'm going to put the login app on the homepage, and a login checker on every page so essentially the question becomes: How can I redirect using a appscript? I tried the html redirect method using a refresh and a url which hasn't worked and a few not noteworthy javascript methods all that have failed.

Edit: Bump!

Comment: Perhaps you can use .htaccess to prevent unauthorized users

Comment: That said, I don't even believe google sites supports .htaccess - I'm not using google app engine to host a site, I'm using the google sites itself. I can't change either since I'm making it for someone else ( I wouldn't ask the question if I was using google app engine)